# How to remove secureboot entry from bios boot menu?

Tags: opensuse

I accidentally booted an opensuse usb in uefi mode and proceeded to install. Since then, I have been stuck with a secure boot entry in my bios boot options. How do I remove it?

Comment: Try setting your Administrator password in the BIOS and then check if you can change it.

Comment: I have set the administrator password but their is no option to remove the entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a password actually did work, the secure boot entry has been removed. However, the change was not immediate.